# DB2 Connection string with SSL Server Certificate on .NET (Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, db2, ibm-cloud

I have been attempting to set up a `DB2 Connection` programmatically, via `.NET`, and I've puzzled with the following findings:

**1. Testing a connection on VS Code**

After installing the `Db2 Connect extension`, I've populated the following fields:

`Database Name`;
`Host`;
`Port`;
`UserID`;
`Password`;

and set the `Checkbox` `Enable SSL Security = true`, in addition to populating the full path of the SSL Server Certificated (saved on my local drive `C:\...crt`).

As a result, the `Db2` connection has been established.

**2. Testing a connection programmatically**

After adding `IBM.Data.DB2.Core` as a `reference` into the project through `NuGet`, I've used in a `Controller`:

```
  using System;
  using IBM.Data.DB2.Core;
  namespace SSLTest
  {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        DB2Command MyDB2Command = null;
        String MyDb2ConnectionString = "database=alias;uid=userid;pwd=password;"; // nub of
        //the issue
        DB2Connection MyDb2Connection = new DB2Connection(MyDb2ConnectionString);
        MyDb2Connection.Open();
        MyDB2Command = MyDb2Connection.CreateCommand();
        MyDB2Command.CommandText = "SELECT * from d.Test";
        ...
        MyDb2DataReader.Close();
        MyDB2Command.Dispose();
        MyDb2Connection.Close();
    }
   }
}
```

To fully replicate programmatically the connection settings described in **1.**, I've used:

```
String MyDb2ConnectionString = "DATABASE=xxxxx;SERVER=xxxxx;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;Security=SSL";
```

where `SERVER = Host`and wonder on the way to add the `SSL Server path`into the connection string. Otherwise the connection would keep failing.

Thanks in advance.
Best

Comment: I am not using C#, but this Db2 docs page discusses the SSL setup for non-Java clients and shows the keywords related to the certificates: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=ctsidc-configuring-tls-support-in-non-java-db2-clients Look for SSLServerCertificate

Comment: @data_henrik: Thanks for routing to the suggested URL, that has helped in re-structuring the ```connection string``` and eventually make the ```secure``` connection work. Best.

Comment: Do you want to put it in as answer?